# Jquery jscrollpane getContentPositionY not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

That's pretty much it. When I try to use the getter getContentPositionY(), the whole script freezes. Any ideas? Or any other way I can get jscrollpane scrollers position would be great.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#text-content').load(function() {
    $('#right').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 10,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 10,
        horizontalDragMinWidth: 10,
        horizontalDragMaxWidth: 10
    });
});

var pane_api = $("#right").data('jsp');
alert(pane_api.getContentPositionY());
});
```

And the markup:

```
<div id="right">
    <img src="pics/BIOGRAPHY/tretji_stolpec/text_bio.png" id="text-content" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#right {
float:left;
width:50%;
height:95%;
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions. Cheers, Val

Comment: need more info (markup, the code where your jsp is initialized), your code itself is correct and should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. The markup and init are irrelevant, since everything else works fine.. I know it's not a lot to go on, but for ex., `pane_api.scrollBy(..)` works etc. So this is really unexplained.. Any ideas? Cheers, Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably misinterpreting this line:

```
$('#text-content').load(function() {
```

load needs an url where to load from. you are just giving a function. what do you want to achieve???

Comment: Ah, yes! That is it! I thought this was weird to use load function, but I've just copy/pasted the code from somewhere. Thank you! Cheers, Val